# How to extract from JSON to create a new JSON files

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON data coming from database dynamically, see below:

```
[["15","0.027","0.137","0.353","0.044","0.111","0.024","2013-07-30 17:45:06"],["17","0.027","0.137","0.353","0.044","0.111","0.024","2013-07-30 17:50:14"],["19","0.017","0.137","0.353","0.044","0.111","0.024","2013-07-30 17:55:35"],["21","0.017","0.137","0.353","0.044","0.111","0.024","2013-07-30 18:00:34"],["23","0.017","0.137","0.353","0.044","0.111","0.024","2013-07-30 18:05:10"],["25","0.017","0.137","0.353","0.044","0.111","0.024","2013-07-30 18:10:07"] and so on..
```

so the structure is as follows `[time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time5, time7, TimeStamp]`

What I need to achieve is to end up with 7 new JSONs to have structure as follows:

```
json1 = [time1,TimeStamp]
json2 = [time2,TimeStamp]
json3 = [time3,TimeStamp]
json4 = [time4,TimeStamp]
and so on..
```

I need this to implement into jQPLot
Can anyone help please? Thank you

Comment: Terminology note, none of what you have there is JSON. It's all just JS arrays.

Comment: it is json_encode($data) coming from php file. Can you help though? Many thanks

Comment: What Rory mean is JSON format is different, it is enclosed by {} and many more rules. What you had is a JS array. If you want to get correct answer, it's better to get terminologies right. A lot of people won't get what you mean even though they might know the answer. And  the solution is probably the answer down here by Scorchio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this (you can find a [ready-to-play jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SPfxT/1/)):

```
// Creates a new array from the items array with the item 
// for the given index and with the last item (timestamp).
function timeNFromItems(items, index) {
    return [items[index], items[items.length - 1]];
}

// Loop over each time index, so that from:
// [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6, time7, timestamp]
// ...the following is printed out:
// time1, timestamp
// time2, timestamp
// [...]
// time7, timestamp
function timesFromItems(items) {
    numberOfTimes = 7;
    result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; ++i) {
        result += timeNFromItems(items, i) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

sample = [
    ["15", "0.027", "0.137", "0.353", "0.044", "0.111", "0.024", "2013-07-30 17:45:06"],
    ["17", "0.027", "0.137", "0.353", "0.044", "0.111", "0.024", "2013-07-30 17:50:14"],
    ["19", "0.017", "0.137", "0.353", "0.044", "0.111", "0.024", "2013-07-30 17:55:35"],
    ["21", "0.017", "0.137", "0.353", "0.044", "0.111", "0.024", "2013-07-30 18:00:34"],
    ["23", "0.017", "0.137", "0.353", "0.044", "0.111", "0.024", "2013-07-30 18:05:10"],
    ["25", "0.017", "0.137", "0.353", "0.044", "0.111", "0.024", "2013-07-30 18:10:07"]
];

alert(timesFromItems(sample[0]));
```

The first function gets a given pair for a "row", the second one just loops over to get all pairs.